# How to delay destruction of unnamed objects?

Tags: rust

I am using the [`TempDir` struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/tempdir/tempdir/struct.TempDir.html?search=) to create and remove folders on disk. The `TempDir` itself is not referenced in the code apart from its construction.

Since the compiler warns about unused objects, I tried (un)naming the TempDir-struct to `_` but this results in the struct immediately being destroyed.

Is there a nice solution to this?

See [example code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=pub%20struct%20Res%3B%0A%0Aimpl%20Drop%20for%20Res%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20drop(%26mut%20self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22Dropping%20self!%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20one()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22one%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20r%20%3D%20Res%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C---%20Dropping%20at%20end%20of%20function%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Before%20exit%22)%3B%0A%7D%0Afn%20two()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22two%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20_%20%3D%20Res%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20%3C---%20Dropping%20immediately%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Before%20exit%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20one()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20two()%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0), compare `one` to `two`:

```
pub struct Res;
impl Drop for Res {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping self!");
    }
}

fn one() {
    println!("one");
    let r = Res; // <--- Dropping at end of function 
                 //      but compiler warns about unused object
    println!("Before exit");
}

fn two() {
    println!("two");
    let _ = Res;  // <--- Dropping immediately
    println!("Before exit");
}

fn main() {
    one();
    two();
}
```

Comment: Use `_unused_but_compiler_does_not_complain_because_of_leading_underscore`, should still work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Giving a variable a name but prefixing the name with an underscore delays destruction until the end of the scope but does not trigger the unused variable warning.

```
struct Noisy;

impl Drop for Noisy {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping");
    }
}

fn main() {
    {
        let _ = Noisy;
        println!("Before end of first scope");
    }

    {
        let _noisy = Noisy;
        println!("Before end of second scope");
    }
}
```

```
Dropping
Before end of first scope
Before end of second scope
Dropping
```